# Does attr_accessor making a new variable that allows accessing an instance variable?

Tags: ruby

Would making a new variable with attr_accessor make a new variable that isnt an instance variable or will it make accessing the instance variable possible?

```
class Whatever
  attr_accessor :var
  @var
end
```

So if i were to do something like a = Whatever.new and a.var = 5. would that set up @var to 5?
Also in Ruby you must have getter and setter methods like we cant do the following

```
class Whatever
  @var = 5
end
a = Whatever.new
puts a.@var
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr_accessor` only creates getter and setter methods. These code examples are equivalent:

```
class Whatever
  attr_accessor :var
end
```

and

```
class Whatever
  def var
    @var
  end

  def var=(value)
    @var = value
  end
end
```

Note also that `@var` defined in `class` body refers to `class` itself, not its instances, so `@var`s in the following example are completely different and non-connected variables:

```
class Whatever
  def var
    @var
  end

  @var = 5
end
Whatever.instance_variable_get(:@var)
# => 5
Whatever.new.instance_variable_get(:@var)
% => nil
```

Comment: so we could make instance variables in either two ways. attr_acessor :var or ilke so `@var = 2` in the initialize method, but with the second method we wouldnt be able to access @var outside the class unless we define a getter and a setter method?

Comment: Not exactly, like I wrote, `attr_accessor` doesn't set any variable, it only defines getter and setter for the specific variable. If you have `attr_accessor` though, you actually can set variable using setter, `self.var = 2` instead of `@var = 2`, but it's not very useful. The main goal of this is to make explicit setting of instance variable possible outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

`attr_accesor` does not create a new variable but instead creates getter and setter methods. [Here](https://dev.to/k_penguin_sato/ruby-getters-and-setters-1p30#what-is-a-setter-method) is a decent article that might help explain better.

There is also `attr_reader` which will only create a getter method and will allow you to access the instance variables as you would a method. That looks like this behind the scenes:

```
def var
  @var
end
```

Another option is `attr_writer` which creates a setter method for the instance variable and that would look like this:

```
def var=(new_var)
  @var = new_var
end
```

However, if you need to both "get" and "set" the variable, you could use `attr_accessor`.

```
class Whatever

  attr_accessor :var

  def initialize
    @var = 5
  end
end

a = Whatever.new
a.var = 6
a.var
=> 6
```